# How to add div panel in html and javascript when clicking submit button in html form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am stuck on an issue in past 3 to 4 days. I have created a student registration form by html and javascript . I have first included validation via javascript and then i included string concatenation in javascript to submit all the values of the form and show it's submission via alert. Now the problem here is that i want to show all submission value in div panel but i am not able to do that because i am an amateur in this field i need little guidance and help in making javascript and html code to include div panel on submit button. I am trying to follow this site: [W3schools link to make div panel](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display_js). Can anybody please help me out to include w3schools code in my code .

My HTML Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Reg Form</title>
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="reg.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body onload="document.registration.inputfirstname.focus();">
    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="registration" onSubmit="return formValidation();">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>
                            <center>Registration</center>
                        </legend>
    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="inputfirstname">First Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="inputfirstname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-md">
    
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="inputlastname">Last Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="inputlastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control input-md">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="inputrollno">Roll No</label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <input type="text" name="textinput" id="inputrollno" placeholder="Roll No" class="form-control input-md">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="inputclass">Class</label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <input type="text" name="textinput" id="inputclass" placeholder="Class" class="form-control input-md">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="inputemail">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="inputemail" placeholder="E-Mail" class="form-control input-md">
    
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <button id="submit" onclick="showme()" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

My Javascript Code:

```js
function formValidation() {
        var inputfirstname = document.registration.inputfirstname;
        var inputlastname = document.registration.inputlastname;
        var inputrollno = document.registration.inputrollno;
        var inputclass = document.registration.inputclass;
        var inputemail = document.registration.inputemail;
    
    
    
        if (firstname_validation(inputfirstname, 5, 12)) {
            if (lastname_validation(inputlastname, 6, 12)) {
                if (allnumeric(inputrollno)) {
                    if (alphanumeric(inputclass)) {
                        if (ValidateEmail(inputemail)) {
                            alert('Form Successfully Submitted');
                            return true;
    
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    
    }
    
    function firstname_validation(inputfirstname, mx, my) {
        var input_firstname_len = inputfirstname.value.length;
        if (input_firstname_len == 0 || input_firstname_len >= my || input_firstname_len < mx) {
            alert("First Name should not be empty / length should be between " + mx + " to " + my);
            inputfirstname.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    function lastname_validation(inputlastname, mx, my) {
        var inputlastname_len = inputlastname.value.length;
        if (inputlastname_len == 0 || inputlastname_len >= my || inputlastname_len < mx) {
            alert("Last Name should not be empty / length should be between " + mx + " to " + my);
            inputlastname.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    function allnumeric(inputrollno) {
        var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if (inputrollno.value.match(numbers)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('Roll No must be in numbers only');
            inputrollno.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    function alphanumeric(inputclass) {
        var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
        if (inputclass.value.match(letters)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('Class must have alphanumeric characters only');
            inputclass.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    function ValidateEmail(inputemail) {
        var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if (inputemail.value.match(mailformat)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
            inputemail.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    var button = document.getElementById('submit');
    function showme() {
    
        var firstname = document.getElementById('inputfirstname');
    var lastname = document.getElementById('inputlastname');
    var rollno = document.getElementById('inputrollno');
    var Class = document.getElementById('inputclass');
    var email = document.getElementById('inputemail');
    
        var str = 'Hello ' + inputfirstname.value + inputlastname.value +', Your Roll no is' + inputrollno.value +',You have successfully registered for this course';
        alert(str); 
    }
```

Pls help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Refer to: [`How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You simply want to display all the field values inside a div. am I correct?

Comment: Yes @Dananjaya Ariyasena

Comment: What should i do to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code

```js
function formValidation() {
    var inputfirstname = document.registration.inputfirstname;
    var inputlastname = document.registration.inputlastname;
    var inputrollno = document.registration.inputrollno;
    var inputclass = document.registration.inputclass;
    var inputemail = document.registration.inputemail;



    if (firstname_validation(inputfirstname, 5, 12)) {
        if (lastname_validation(inputlastname, 6, 12)) {
            if (allnumeric(inputrollno)) {
                if (alphanumeric(inputclass)) {
                    if (ValidateEmail(inputemail)) {
                        alert('Form Successfully Submitted');
                        return true;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;

}

function firstname_validation(inputfirstname, mx, my) {
    var input_firstname_len = inputfirstname.value.length;
    if (input_firstname_len == 0 || input_firstname_len >= my || input_firstname_len < mx) {
        alert("First Name should not be empty / length should be between " + mx + " to " + my);
        inputfirstname.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function lastname_validation(inputlastname, mx, my) {
    var inputlastname_len = inputlastname.value.length;
    if (inputlastname_len == 0 || inputlastname_len >= my || inputlastname_len < mx) {
        alert("Last Name should not be empty / length should be between " + mx + " to " + my);
        inputlastname.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function allnumeric(inputrollno) {
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if (inputrollno.value.match(numbers)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Roll No must be in numbers only');
        inputrollno.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function alphanumeric(inputclass) {
    var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if (inputclass.value.match(letters)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Class must have alphanumeric characters only');
        inputclass.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function ValidateEmail(inputemail) {
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if (inputemail.value.match(mailformat)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
        inputemail.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
var button = document.getElementById('submit');
function showme() {

    var firstname = document.getElementById('inputfirstname');
var lastname = document.getElementById('inputlastname');
var rollno = document.getElementById('inputrollno');
var classInput = document.getElementById('inputclass');
var email = document.getElementById('inputemail');

    var str = 'Hello s ' + inputfirstname.value + inputlastname.value +', Your Roll no is' + inputrollno.value +',You have successfully registered for this course';
    //alert(str);
    
    document.getElementById('formData').innerHTML = 'First Name : ' + firstname.value + '<br>Last Name : ' + lastname.value + '<br>Roll No : ' + rollno.value +'<br>Class : ' + classInput.value + '<br>Email : ' + email.value ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Reg Form</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="reg.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="document.registration.inputfirstname.focus();">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form class="form-horizontal" name="registration" onSubmit="return formValidation();">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>
                        <center>Registration</center>
                    </legend>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="inputfirstname">First Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="inputfirstname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-md">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="inputlastname">Last Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="inputlastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control input-md">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="inputrollno">Roll No</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" name="textinput" id="inputrollno" placeholder="Roll No" class="form-control input-md">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="inputclass">Class</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" name="textinput" id="inputclass" placeholder="Class" class="form-control input-md">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="inputemail">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="inputemail" placeholder="E-Mail" class="form-control input-md">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <button id="submit" onclick="showme()" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="formData"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have given me this example thanks for giving this example. Again i want to ask that this snippet is submitting and showing details in an alert. I have to change the div id name to show it on a panel on a same page?

Comment: You can use alert and any `id` name. yes, if you have some panel then use that panel `id` name.

Comment: ok bro now i understood it. i will be get back to if i still face  any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can add div with some `id` property like this : 
`<div id="formData"></div>`

Then whenever you want to display something :

```
var firstname = document.getElementById('inputfirstname'); //input
document.getElementById('formData').innerText = 'First Name : ' + firstname.value;
```

Comment: I can change the div id panel to div id form or div id form data. That's all you are trying to say. I want to ask just last thing which is that where should i include this panel code in my code. The code snippet is of my code. Where i should create new div as told by you and where should i include javascript code in my code. Can you please help me out. I will be very grateful to you?

Comment: You can add `<div>`  outside the form ( `<form></form>` ) in html page. and script part you can add end of the `showme()` function

Comment: ok brother i don't have to put the javascript code in the javascript code file. I have to include this code in html file. Are you 100% sure it will work . I have tried before asking this question but my button doesn't work by adding html and javascript code in the same file . Can you please find some solution to it?

Comment: As I know it doesn't matter where you adding script, it will work. because you are using a form tag, some issues may occur.

Comment: ok bro i will try to solve my problem . If i get stuck somewhere i will get back to you again.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a row and inside it 5 cells. then in showme() function you can assign values to these cells.

```
                       <div class="row" id="studentDetail" sytle="display: 
                         none;">
                        <div class="col-sm-2" id="firstName"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2" id="lastName"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2" id="rolNo"></div>
                          <div class="col-sm-2" id="class"></div>
                         <div class="col-sm-2" id="email"></div>

                       </div>

                function showme() {

                    var firstname = document.getElementById('inputfirstname');
                    var lastname = document.getElementById('inputlastname');
                    var rollno = document.getElementById('inputrollno');
                    var Class = document.getElementById('inputclass');
                    var email = document.getElementById('inputemail');

                 //now set these values to div elements of the row

                  document.getElementById("firstName").text(firsname.value);
                  document.getElementById("lastName").text(lastname.value);
                  document.getElementById("rolNo").text(rollno.value);
                  document.getElementById("class").text(Class.value);
                  document.getElementById("email").text(email.value);
                  //now show the hidden div
                  document.getElementById("studentDetail").style.display = "block";
               }
```

Comment: you can use innerText instead of .text(). for example document.getElementById("firstName").innerText=firsname.value;

Comment: ok @Ali you are trying to say that i should use document.getElementById to show all the values in the form. Can you suggest me where should i use string in this code?

Comment: ok @Ali where should i use string values in this code? like : var str = 'Hello ' + inputfirstname.value + inputlastname.value +', Your Roll no is' + inputrollno.value +',You have successfully registered for this course';

Comment: <div class="row col-sm-12 alert-success" id="stringValue" sytle="display: none;">
Hello! <span id="firstName"></span><span id="lastName"></span><span id="rolNo"></span>
 You have successfully registered for this course
</div>

now in showme() function add this code.
 document.getElementById("firstName").innerText=firsname.value;
document.getElementById("lastName").innerText=lastname.value;
document.getElementById("rolNo").innerText=rollno.value;

show the hidden div
document.getElementById("stringValue").style.display = "block";